# Is binding data to template elements in Backbone considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, data-binding, jquery-data

In my Backbone.js app, one of my views renders a table via a template.

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'table',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(template({ this.model.attributes });
    }
});
```

I need to bind some data to the table rows. But they are created within the template. Is it ok to add a method to my view where I bind data to each element using jQuery's `.data()` function or is that considered bad practice in Backbone circles?

Edit: My implicit question is if there's a more Backboneish way to do this, if the answer is that it is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be considered a code smell: the goal for Backbone is to manage application state in javascript INSTEAD of shoving stuff in the DOM. If you want to render a collection take a look at (e.g.) http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/9-collection-views-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js/#.Uuol5K3JjmE

Or if you're open to Backbone-based frameworks, look at Marionette's composite view (which is a Marionette collection view that will allow you to display tables). There's a blog post on that here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I will look into the blog posts.

Comment: Just one question though: In my case, the table rows represents objects within the main model. Let's say the table represents a CompanyModel, and each row represents an EmployeeModel. Now, I want to bind the data associated with each employee with the table row. Do I instantiate new models for each row within the TableView?

Comment: The easiest to manage (and the Marionette does it) is to have one model per employee, each with their own view (each view would be one row). This way you can easily manage the small templates, and related events.